# Problema con propiedad hover css

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo un botón que al pasar el mouse se muestran dos botones, pero tengo un error que al momento de dar clic en un botón de los dos que se muestran éstos se pierden. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Éste es mi código:

```css
.stBoton {
    padding: 10px;
}

.opciones {
    color: red;
    display: none;
}

.stBoton:hover + .opciones {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" class="stBoton">
        click
    </button>
    <div class="opciones">
        <button type="button" class="stBoton">
            click1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="stBoton">
            click2
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

La idea es que se mantengan los dos botones que se muestran y que se pierdan después de dar clic en uno de ellos. ¿Es posible con CSS puro?

Comment: Es necesario solo con CSS?

Comment: si o si es posible con angularjs que con eso tambien estoy trabajando

Comment: ¿[Esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79579/2089) sirvió @DiegoIsraelMoreno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí hay una solución sólo con CSS:

```css
.stBoton{
    padding: 10px;
}
.opciones{
    color: red;
    display: none;
}

.stBoton:hover + .opciones,
.opciones:hover{
    display: block;
}
.opciones:active{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button type="button" class="stBoton">
        click
    </button>
    <div  class="opciones">
        <button type="button" class="stBoton active-uno">
            click1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="stBoton active-dos">
            click2
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo perdón por la demora.